# Why I dont get what I'm looking for

Tags: php

I'm trying to create list item where the information comes from php, which grabs it from a .txt saved in the same directory.  I have some HTML with my layout and some php files with the functions that I use.

**This is the html:** So I grab the variables from php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Folks On Your Mailing List</h1>
       <?php
         if($register_users){
            foreach ($register_users as $user) {
               list($name,$email) = $user;
               echo "<li> $name :<a href='mailto:$email'>$email</a></li>";
               }
          } else{
             echo "No register menbers";
          }
       ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the php were I include the template and the function that I will use.**

```
<?php 
    include "../functions.php";

    $register_users = get_registered_users();


    include "registered_user.tmpl.php";



?>
```

**And last but not least the function**

```
function get_registered_users($path = MAILING_LIST){
    $users = file($path);



    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $name =  explode(": ", $user);
        return $name ;
    }
```

The $path is a constant defined in this same document but it's OK - that's not the problem.  The problem comes when returning $name and assigning it to $registers_users which will be passed to the template.  It only prints the first letter of the name and the first letter of the email.

Comment: You `return` in a `foreach` loop. It won't get past one iteration.

Comment: You are `RETURN`ing in a foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something more like:

```
function get_registered_users($path = MAILING_LIST) {
    $users = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $output = array(); //Create an array to hold the array($parts)
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $parts = explode(": ", $user);
        $output[] = $parts; //Add the $parts to the bigger array
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return it ends the function. If you want all the users, you'll want to return that array outside of your foreach loop. But since $users is already an array, you don't even need the foreach loop, aside from doing the explode.